# Facebook OAuth acces_denied error in WebApi GetExternalLogin action

Tags: facebook, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin, access-denied

I'm experiencing an issue with Facebook OAuth on my production server. It works without any issue locally, but when i publish it to Azure it falls over in this method in the Account controller on my WebApi

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
```

The error parameter is not null, and has the value "access_denied" which is stopping the process from proceeding. I'm finding it infuriatingly difficult to debug this issue.

My Facebook developer console is configured correctly with the correct domains and OAuth redirect URLs because when I change them I get stuck on facebook with an error saying the redirect URL is incorrect.

I've been scouring the internet for answers to this with very little luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even if i am able to get a more descriptive error that "access_denied"

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you want to see any more code. Here is my WebApiStartup class

```
facebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = WebConfig.OAuthFacebookClientId,
            AppSecret = WebConfig.OAuthFacebookClientSecret,
            //CallbackPath = new PathString("/api/account/signin-facebook/"),
            Provider = new FacebookAuthProvider()
        };
        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthOptions);

OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, userManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tokenExpiry),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
            {
                OnCreate = CreateAccessToken,
                OnReceive = ReceiveAccessToken
            },
            AuthorizationCodeProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
            {
                OnCreate = CreateAuthenticationCode,
                OnReceive = ReceiveAuthenticationCode
            }
        };
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);

OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();                                    
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was the IP addresses I had entered into Facebook Developer console for my WebApi on Azure had changed.

Changing these to the correct ones fixed the problem.